# A strange series of questions

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, story

Our agency have extracted some information from a terrorist's USB drive; According to our intelligence, this supposed to point us to the six potential cities their leader's current safe house might be in. But all we got from the disk is a .txt file containing these series of weird question with seemingly a lot of typos.

```
 an you tell me the definition of agony?

 Where should I visit on holidy?

 What will happen if one of the 
 residential candidate
 is me?

 s a cellar spider capable of flying? 

 Can our group idenified as Japanese shadow warriors?

 Cn I choose a lone beast?

 cue:

 RE: / RE: PHD, H. / RE: RA, S./ RE: I then GQ.
```

Can you help us identify all the six potential cities?

---

Hint:

> No answer needed.

Hint II:

> `RE: MOV, E. /`

Hint III:

> Solving the questions will get you **country names** and from there you need something else to tell you which city it is (from those countries).

Hint IV:

> If you know the `cue`, you know the `questions`, but beware the `DISTRACTION`!

Addendum:

```
1. (EU) 2. (WA) 3. (ME) 4. (NA) 5. (WA) 6. (OC)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The letters missing from the misspelt words

> spell the word CAPITAL:
>  **c**an
>  holid**a**y
>  **p**residential
>  **i**s
>  iden**t**ified
>  c**a**n
>  c**l**ue
>
>  So it looks like we're looking for the capitals of the six countries.

```
Addendum: 1. (EU) 2. (WA) 3. (ME) 4. (NA) 5. (WA) 6. (OC)
```

> I think this means that country #1 is in Europe, #2 and #5 in West Africa, #3 in the Middle East, #4 in North America and #6 in Oceania.

```
1. an you tell me the definition of agony?
```

> Can you tell me what i**s pain**? Spain is in Europe, so it matches the addendum.
>  The capital is **Madrid**.

```
2. Where should I visit on holidy?
```

> Where **to go** on holiday? Togo is in West Africa.
>  The capital is **Lomé**.

```
3. What will happen if one of the 
residential candidate
is me?
```

> **I ran** for president. Iran is in the Middle East (from @NudgeNudge)
>  The capital is **Tehran**.

```
4. s a cellar spider capable of flying?
```

> **Can a da**ddy longlegs fly? Canada is in North America.
>  Capital: **Ottawa**.

```
5. Can our group idenified as Japanese shadow warriors?
```

> Can our group **be nin**jas? Benin is in West Africa. (from @NudgeNudge)
>  Capital: **Porto-Novo**.

```
6. Cn I choose a lone beast?
```

> Can I choose a **solo mons**ter? The Solomon (Island)s are in Oceania.
>  Capital: **Honiara**.

Comment: Very good start! And let me tell you this, rot13(Pyhr vf abg arprffnel arrqrq gb fbyir guvf chmmyr, vg’f zber yvxr na vafgehpgvba ba ubj gb rkgenpg gur pbhagel anzrf sebz gur dhrfgvbaf tvira ohg lbh pna whfg svthevat bhg gur vafgehpgvba lbhefrys ol gevny naq reebe.) Also, the third (candidate) country is not correct, for it does not fit the way you required to solve the question but it’s cool enough for me to want to accept it.

Comment: I think 3 is rot13(Vena (V ena sbe cerfvqrag)) and maybe 5 is rot13(Orava (or avawn?))

Comment: @NudgeNudge Thanks, I think you're right! Added.

Comment: @jafe Since you don’t need the clue now, I’m gonna tell you how to crack it (based on the hint that is already given) rot13(sebz uvag VV, >erzbir nyy gur flzobyf< naq sebz uvag VI, >erzbir gur "**qvfgenpgvba**”.<)